# Inhomogeneous eigenvalue problem, the shooting method and constraints

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, constraints

In trying to solve a problem occurring in QM calculations I've encountered the following pickle, with which I hope you could help me.
I am trying to solve an inhomogeneous eigenvalue differential equation:
$$ 
  y''(x) + (\lambda+f(x))y(x)=g(x) 
$$
with the boundary conditions $y(0) = y(\infty) = 0$.

I am using Numerov's algorithm to integrate $y(x)$, by interpolating with $y_{n+1} = F(y_n, y_{n-1})$, and I'm estimating the eigenvalue using the shooting method (that is by examining the tail of the function, until it matches the boundary condition at infinity).

The question is: I have to impose a second, more strenuous restriction on $y(x)$. As often occurs in QM, the norm of the function has to be unity. In other words:
$$
  \int y(x)^2 \textrm{d}\omega(x)=1 
$$

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to incorporate this condition, **and** retain the shooting method. Firstly, I tried adjusting the parameter that commences the integration; that is, for Numerov's method I have to specify two initial values for $y_0, y_1$. $y_1$ is generally arbitrary and I can calibrate it. But, if the trial eigenvalue itself is very distant from an actual eigenvalue, this diff. eq. admits an exponentially exploding solution which is **not** influenced by the parameter $y_1$. In trying to optimise the norm of the function in this case, my code stalls.
Furthermore, I haven't exactly figured out how to make optimizing $y_1$ automatic, if I *do* somehow manage to place the initial eigenvalue close to an actual stationary state.
In a nutshell, what is the best strategy you would recommend to add this second constraint on the BVP? What would a general code implementing it look like?

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct here, which is rather biased based on my own experiences, would be to try a spectral method. That is, cut off the domain at some large $L$, artificially require $y(L)=0$, and then approximate $y$ as a truncated Fourier sine series. This seems nice for this application because the problem is linear, or at least is linear for each fixed $\lambda$, and the coefficient on the derivative is constant.

When you write the equation in Fourier space, you get

$$K \hat{y} + \widehat{fy} + \lambda \hat{y} = \hat{g} \\
\| \hat{y} \|^2_2 = 1.$$

Here $K$ is a diagonal matrix with $K_{jj}=-\frac{j^2 \pi^2}{L^2}$ and the norm in the second equation is just the Euclidean norm. This is technically an inhomogeneous matrix eigenvalue problem, because the map $\hat{y} \to \widehat{fy}$ is linear. It should really not be posed as a matrix eigenvalue problem, however. This is because the matrix defining $\hat{y} \mapsto \widehat{fy}$ is probably dense, which would mean that it takes $O(N^2)$ time to multiply it with a vector. By contrast the time to do the procedure $\hat{y} \to y \to fy \to \widehat{fy}$ is $O(N \log(N))$ using the fast Fourier transform. This means that good methods for solving it are black box methods which only need to evaluate $Ax$.

I actually expected that methods of this type would be quite standard, but on a quick search I did not find very much, especially among recent work. I did find this paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379587901236 which deals with the problem by power iteration. (The first algorithm is stated on page 11.) One nice thing about their approach for this problem is that the normalization of the vector is essentially "built in".

Comment: Thanks; I've read about discrete fourier methods before, but didn't see them as applicable to this case (perhaps, incorrectly). both f and g are in $L^2$, (satisfying, f(0)=f(L)=0) decaying rapidly.

Comment: @DanielAkkerman Are they also smooth? (Spectral methods suffer greatly when the coefficient functions are not sufficiently smooth.)

Comment: Yes, they're smooth  -- and in theory -- infinitely differentiable.

Comment: @DanielAkkerman That means that in theory you should need rather few Fourier basis functions--probably less than 100--to apply my suggestion.

Comment: I would really appreciate it, if you could delineate -- or point me to where I could find it -- the procedure for obtaining the mapping of $\tilde {y} \mapsto y$, and  thus f * y

Comment: @DanielAkkerman For mapping between $y$ and $\hat{y}$ you should use the fast Fourier transform. For that I would recommend not reinventing the wheel: you can use FFTW in C or the implementation in MATLAB, or many other options. For mapping from $\hat{y}$ to $\widehat{fy}$, the scheme is: $\hat{y} \to y \to fy \to \widehat{fy}$. The first and last steps are Fourier transforms; the middle step is just evaluation of $f$ and ordinary multiplication.

Comment: @DanielAkkerman (Cont.) Note that although it would be intuitively convenient to get the matrix representation of the map $\hat{y} \to \widehat{fy}$, this approach is actually slower than the procedure I just described. This is especially true if you precompute $f$ at the required points.

Comment: Can MATLAB transform unknown functions -- y(x)? Or would you have me estimate (in the usual way) y first, and then subject it to the minimization scheme?

Comment: @DanielAkkerman I thought about it a little more and realized that an optimization approach is probably an awkward way to deal with the problem. I'm writing a different suggestion now (still based on a spectral method).

Comment: @DanielAkkerman I've finished my edit. Note that it does indeed require some initial guess for the solution.

Comment: Thanks again. I've actually read that article (review) you posted, and saw that mainly, in terms of finding an estimate for the eigenvalues my best option is with inverse iteration. One more question though, do you think this will still work if my norm is not Euclidean? The measure with which y(x) is integrated is actually weighed by "x", so it's not a question of simply summing y-tuples.

Comment: @DanielAkkerman Do you mean that $\int_0^\infty x y(x)^2 dx = 1$? That complicates matters a bit for my suggested approach, but I don't think it is so bad, because that norm is induced by the inner product $(u,v)=\langle \sqrt{x}u,\sqrt{x}v \rangle$.

Comment: @DanielAkkerman Indeed, provided you can ensure that $y$ decays fast enough at $\infty$, you might solve for $z=\sqrt{x}y$ using essentially my approach (but where now the derivatives also require transforming forward and back), and then back-solve for $y$.